# Django Admin image upload not saving on database

Tags: python, database, django, model

I need to resize an image before saving to the database, so i am overriding the save method:

```
from PIL import Image

class Categorias(models.Model):
image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False,null=True)
image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False,null=True)
the_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/image/category",width_field="image_width",height_field="image_height")

def save(self):
    if not self.id and not self.the_image:
        return;

    image = Image.open(self.the_image)
    ratio_height = (890*self.image_height)/self.image_width     
    size = (890,ratio_height)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(self.the_image.path)
```

The image is resized and writed to my media folder, but the problem is that the registries isnt saved on the database.

I don´t know what i am missing.

---

toad013  helped me and i could save the registries to the database but  then i got two images being writing to my media folder, one as original and another resized with this code:

```
def save(self):
    if not self.id and not self.the_image:
        return;

    image = Image.open(self.the_image)
    ratio_height = (890*self.image_height)/self.image_width     
    size = (890,ratio_height)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(self.the_image.path)     
    super(Categorias, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should still need to call the original save function to save the object

```
super(Categorias, self).save()
```

Comment: Now the registries is being saved to the database, but now i have the original image being saved with the original width and height and the resize version. Is possible just have the resized version?

Comment: hmmm remove the image.save(...) and make sure the "super" line is at the end and before the super just assign the new resized image you made: "self.image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)" . This way you let django do all the saving and updating of the fields

Comment: Getting: TypeError at /admin/imagens/categorias/add/
'tuple' object is not callable

Exception Value: 
'tuple' object is not callable

def save(self):
  if not self.id and not self.the_image:
   return;

  image = Image.open(self.the_image)
  ratio_height = (890*self.image_height)/self.image_width  
  size = (890,ratio_height)
  image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  #image.save(self.the_image.path)
  self.image = image.size(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  super(Categorias, self).save()

Comment: image.resize not image.size ... and self.the_image (sorry typo on my part) basically your assigning the resized image from "image.resize" to self.the_image and then just have django save the object

Comment: Getting:
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
width

Comment: I did self.the_image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

Comment: actually, yeah you can't do that because PIL returns an Image object and django doesn't know what that is... this is different from your original question though... you might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359880/save-image-created-via-pil-to-django-model