# Django Python PIL save image - broken image

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I am overriding the `save_model` method of modelAdmin to resize the image to 650 which is being uploaded via admin page:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    basewidth = 650
    img = PIL.Image.open(form.cleaned_data['image_file'])

    if img.size[0] > basewidth:
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

        img_filefield = getattr(obj, 'image_file')
        random_image_name = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(30)) + '.jpeg'
        img.save(random_image_name)
        img_filefield.save(random_image_name, ContentFile(img))
        obj.save()
    else:
        obj.save()
```

it is saving the image, but the image is broken, just a black image with `"invalid image"` if I open it.

what am I doing wrong in above code?

Answer (score 0):

I didnot know that PIL Images are of different type than Django ImageField type. Thanks to Skitz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544525/903790), I could solve it this way:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    basewidth = 650
    img = PIL.Image.open(form.cleaned_data['image_file'])

    if img.size[0] > basewidth:
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

        img_file_lang = getattr(obj, 'image_file')
        random_image_name = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(30)) + '.jpeg'

        image_io = StringIO.StringIO()
        img.save(image_io, format='JPEG')

        img_file_lang.save(random_image_name, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()))
        obj.save()
    else:
        obj.save()
```

dont forget to do: `import StringIO`