# Django: resize image before upload

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I want to resize image(**Pillow**) before upload, I write code below but doesn't work!
**and get error:**

> AttributeError at /myapp/list/
>
> _committed
>
> Request Method:   POST
>
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/list/
> Django Version:   1.8 Exception Type:     AttributeError Exception Value:
>
> _committed
>
> Exception Location:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Pillow-2.8.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py
>
> In **getattr**, line 622 Python Executable:   /usr/bin/python3.4 Python
> Version:  3.4.0

**views.py**

```
def list(request):
# Handle file upload
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        imga = request.FILES['docfile']
        size = (600, 400)
        im = Image.open(imga)
        imga = im.resize(size)
        request.FILES['docfile'] = imga
        newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'], namefile=request.POST['namefile'])
        newdoc.save()

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
else:
    form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()

# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render_to_response(
    'myapp/list.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Comment: Not related to your issue, but rather the question's title: you are aware that you are resizing you image on the server side, so technically *after* the upload (and not before).

Answer (score 29):

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from resizeimage import resizeimage

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=your_get_file_path_callback)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.image)
        new_image = resizeimage.resize_width(pil_image_obj, 100)

        new_image_io = BytesIO()
        new_image.save(new_image_io, format='JPEG')

        temp_name = self.image.name
        self.image.delete(save=False)  

        self.image.save(
            temp_name,
            content=ContentFile(new_image_io.getvalue()),
            save=False
        )

        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

P.S. for resizing I've used 'python-image-resize' https://github.com/charlesthk/python-resize-image

Comment: What happens when you just assign `self.image = new_image_io`

Answer (score 0):

For image resizing you can make use of djanof easy thumbnail library.

Below is the sample code,that i have used in my project

```
options = {'size': (200, 200), 'crop': True}
thumb_url =get_thumbnailer(image path).get_thumbnail(options).url
```

For reference https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

There have been some helpful answers, but you might want to understand what is going on with your current code.

Your code raises that exception because of this line :

```
request.FILES['docfile'] = imga
```

What is wrong with that ? You are affecting a pillow `Image` object to a django `ImageField` element. Those are two different types and when you call you `Document` constructor, it might expect to find a file form field that contains a `_committed` attribute.