# How we create different scale images after uploaded in django

Tags: django, image, image-uploading, image-scaling

In my Django project, the user can upload images. I want to create different versions of the uploaded images, like "small size", "large size", and "medium size". How can I do that?

Is there any library that does that, or does Django have a build-in facility to create versions of images?

Comment: check https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30435175/3033586