# Django 1.11: Flip image horizontally before saving into a Django model

Tags: django

I'm doing this application where I take a user's image and then flip it horizontally using `ImageOps` from the `Pillow` library. To do so I made a model like above:

```
from django.db import models


class ImageClient(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
```

I made a form using `ImageField` with a html form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and in my views I did the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ImageForm
from .models import ImageClient
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

def new(request):
    """
    Returns mirror image from client.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = Image.open(form.cleaned_data['image'])
            image = ImageOps.mirror(image)
            form_image = ImageClient(image=image)
            form_image.save()
            return redirect('img:detail', pk=form_image.id)
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'img/new_egami.html', {'form':form})
....
```

As you see, when a check if the form is valid, I open the form's image and flip it horizontally (using `ImageOps.mirror()`) then I save it. But I always getting this error `'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'`. I know the `Image object` is from Pillow, but I do not understand this error. Can someone explain and/or solve this error?

Comment: `ImageField` must have an `upload_to` attribute: `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='folder-to-upload-photos/', null=False, blank=False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raised because the image is a `PIL Image` object, whereas Django is expecting and requires its own `File` object. You could save the Image object to an absolute file path and then refer to it, but there are more efficient ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723220/how-do-you-convert-a-pil-image-to-a-django-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434323/django-resize-image-before-upload/30435175#30435175). Here is an adaptation of @madzohan's answer in the latter link for your image operation:

```
# models.py

from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

class ImageClient(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to="image/path/")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.image)
        new_image = ImageOps.mirror(pil_image_obj)

        new_image_io = BytesIO()
        new_image.save(new_image_io, format='JPEG')

        temp_name = self.image.name
        self.image.delete(save=False)  

        self.image.save(
            temp_name,
            content=ContentFile(new_image_io.getvalue()),
            save=False
        )

        super(ImageClient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and views.py:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    new_image = form.save()
    return redirect('img:detail', pk=new_image.id)
```