# 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed' error when using PIL

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to compress uploaded images(`FileField`). However I'm getting an error which I believe is a problem of double saving? (saving my image, and then saving the whole form which includes the image). I wanted to perform `commit=False` when I'm saving the image but it doesn't appear it's possible. Here's my code:

```
...
if form_post.is_valid():
    instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user

if instance.image:
    filename = instance.image
    instance.image = Image.open(instance.image)
    instance.image.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    instance.image.save(filename, quality=60)

instance.save()
```

returns `'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'` error on the last line (`instance.save()`)

Can someone identify the problem? - and any idea how I can fix it?

Full Traceback:

```
File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/site/post/views.py" in post
  68.                 if uploaded_file_type(instance) is True:

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/site/functions/helper_functions.py" in uploaded_file_type
  12.     f = file.image.read(1024)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /post/
Exception Value: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Full models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and the accompanying `PostForm`:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'title'})

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'user',
            'title',
            'image',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def post(request):    
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)

            if instance.image:
                filename = instance.image
                instance.image = Image.open(instance.image)
                instance.image.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                instance.image.save(filename, quality=60)

            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'form_post': form_post,
        }

        return render(request, 'post/post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

This following code:

```
if instance.image:
    im = Image.open(instance.image)
    print("Filename:", im.filename) #doesn't print anything
    thumb = im.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb.save(im.filename, quality=60)
```

returns an `AttributeError` : `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'`. I believe this is because `im.filename` doesn't print anything. Any idea why?

The other method:

```
if instance.image:
    im = Image.open(instance.image)
    thumb = im.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    thumb.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=60)
    instance.image.save(im.filename, ContentFile(thumb_io.get_value()), save=False)
```

also returns `AttributeError` : `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'`, on this line: `thumb.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=60)`. Not sure why though?

Comment: You say "returns `'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'` error on the last line (`instance.save()`)" but  the traceback shows `'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'` at `if uploaded_file_type(instance) is True:` which is not included in your code sample. You will also need to show your `uploaded_file_type` helper function.

Comment: Please upload your model and your full view (with indentation)

Comment: You must use a subclass of the django File object, instead of a PIL Image. See this answer for how to save the Image to the correct type using an in-memory BytesIO. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710093/1977847

Comment: There are multiple other questions about using Pillow Images with django model.FileField, but since there's a bouny on this question, I can't use the "duplicate" feature. This answer should also work in this case, I think. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42846368/1977847 The last 3 lines are the important ones.

Comment: @HåkenLid Both of those methods don't work - I've added the attempts in my edit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must pass an instance of django's `File` object to [`FileField.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) to change the content of a file field. It works a bit differently from other types of model fields.

> **FieldFile.save(name, content, save=True)**
>
> This method takes a filename and file contents and passes them to the
> storage class for the field, then associates the stored file with the
> model field. If you want to manually associate file data with
> FileField instances on your model, the save() method is used to
> persist that file data.

```
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

if instance.image:
    im = Image.open(instance.image)
    im.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    im.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=60)
    instance.image.save(im.filename, ContentFile(thumb_io.getvalue()), save=False)
instance.save()
```

But if you are not using a remote file storage backend, you could just overwrite the file itself. The file was created when you called `form.save()`. Since you are using the same filename and location, you don't really have to touch the model or tell django that you are messing with the file itself.

```
if instance.image:
    im = Image.open(instance.image)
    im.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(im.filename, quality=60)
```

Comment: Both methods don't work, i've added my attempts in my edit if you could look. I use remote S3 storage but I'm just testing in my local development environment now. But why does it matter whether it's a remote backend or not - the setup is still the same (static_root, media_root etc, just different locations?

Comment: If you use S3, you have to use the `instance.image.save` method. `PIL.Image.save` will only save to the local file system. It doesn't know about django storage backends.

Comment: Right I get you. But the problem with the first method is `thumb.save(thumb_io, im.format, quality=60)` returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'` - when I print `thumb` it prints `None` - any idea?

Comment: Ah. I made a mistake. I thought Image.thumbnail() should return a new Image object, but instead it modifies the Image object in place and returns `None`. I've corrected the code in my answer now.

Comment: in the first code block, line 9, `thumb_io.get_value()` should be `thumb_io.getvalue()` (no underscore in `getvalue()`)

Comment: @HåkenLid thanks for posting and updating the ans. it helped to overcome major pain point for image compression. kudos to u.