# Django 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django

So I have been trying to resize the images uploaded to my projects page of my personal website but for some reason it is throwing me an error.

I am trying PIL to resize but it keeps to throwing me the attribute error whenever I post my post with the uploaded image.

MY code is down below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.
class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files/',blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Opening the image to be resized
        r_image = Image.open(self.images)

        # Resizing the image from the imagefield
        new_image = r_image.resize((96, 96), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.images = new_image

        # Generates a random string 
        unique_string = get_random_string(length=32)

        # Combines title and unique string to slugify
        slugtext = self.title + "-" + "unique_id=-" + unique_string
        self.slug = slugify(slugtext)

        return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would appreciate your answers!

Oh! here is my full traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/personalwebsite/projects/views.py", line 21, in create_projects
    project_form.save()
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 456, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/personalwebsite/projects/models.py", line 39, in save
    return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1282, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1235, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1235, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1234, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1184, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/home/erichardson/env01/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 285, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: Post the error message with full traceback please. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227183/jpegimagefile-object-has-no-attribute-committed-error-when-using-pil)

Comment: @Selcuk Hey man! I added the traceback. Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: @Selcuk Hey bro its working! thanks for sending me that link!