# 'Canvas' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm trying to save the canvas object to my django model field file but it says "'Canvas' object has no attribute '_committed'".

```
p.setTitle(f"{patient.first_name} {patient.last_name}'s Report")
p.showPage()
p.save()

pdf:bytes =buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
response.write(pdf)    

r = Result.objects.filter(score="12").update_or_create(file=p)
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: You can not use an `.update_or_create(..)` for a `.filter(..)`.

Comment: Sorry I just wrote this code as an example just to give you guys an idea of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

"You must pass an instance of django's File object to `FileField.save()` to change the content of a file field. It works a bit differently from other types of model fields." Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227183/jpegimagefile-object-has-no-attribute-committed-error-when-using-pil)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an [**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update_or_create) after a [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter). What you probably wanted is to use:

```
Result.objects.update_or_create(
    score='12',
    defaults={'file': p}
)
```

This will however *not* work with `p`: `p` is not a file, it is a `Canvas` object. You can use the file name, or work with a [**`FieldFile`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile).

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of using

```
buffer =BytesIO()
buffer.close()
```

I used

```
buffer.seek(0)
r = Result.objects.get(pk=result_id)    
r.file.save(f"{d}.pdf", File(buffer))
```

and it worked.